# hadoop compilation - in the dfs file

Tags: java, hadoop, jar, compiler-errors

I want to compile hadoop example with the following commands, but an error occur:
[image]

```
$ mkdir wordcount_classes
$ javac -classpath ${HADOOP_HOME}/hadoop-${HADOOP_VERSION}-core.jar -d wordcount_classes WordCount.java
$ jar -cvf /usr/joe/wordcount.jar -C wordcount_classes/ .

Assuming that:

    /usr/joe/wordcount/input - input directory in HDFS
    /usr/joe/wordcount/output - output directory in HDFS

Sample text-files as input:

$ bin/hadoop dfs -ls /usr/joe/wordcount/input/
/usr/joe/wordcount/input/file01
/usr/joe/wordcount/input/file02

$ bin/hadoop dfs -cat /usr/joe/wordcount/input/file01
Hello World Bye World

$ bin/hadoop dfs -cat /usr/joe/wordcount/input/file02
Hello Hadoop Goodbye Hadoop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/usr/joe` is local, as you can see when you execute the `ls` command on the first line. The second command requires input and output in HDFS locations, but `/usr/joe` doesn't exist on the HDFS. You need to move your data onto the HDFS and then execute the command. For example:

```
#This creates a folder "wordcount/input" in your HDFS home directory
hdfs dfs -mkdir -p wordcount/input
hdfs dfs -put /usr/joe/wordcount/input/* wordcount/input
```

Comment: Ok...in HDFS directory I just  have to files (datanode /namenode) ,does /usr/joe  should be i a directory in HDFS or i can make it ?

Comment: I'd advise adding the data to your home directory, which in your case looks like it's probably `/user/justcbuser`.